# If image width is less than X, add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

As the title suggests, I'm looking to have a little bit of jQuery - if an image is less than a defined width, it adds a class a certain element. This, for me, seems pretty easy but for some reason it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var image = $('.work-each img');
        if (image.width() < 500) {
            $('.work-text').addClass('work-text-small');
        }
});
```

This, should, add a class 'work-text-small' to the element 'work-text' if the image found under each .work-each is less than 500px.

Example of HTML (for each)

```
<div class="work-each">
   <div>
      <img src=""/>
      <div class="work-text">
         <p>Title</p>
         <p>Text</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="work-each">
   <div>
      <img src=""/>
      <div class="work-text">
         <p>Title</p>
         <p>Text</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="work-each">
   <div>
      <img src=""/>
      <div class="work-text">
         <p>Title</p>
         <p>Text</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
R

Comment: Post relevant HTML please

Comment: If you try to console.log the width you're getting it's probably zero, as the image has'nt loaded when you try to get the width. You'll have to wait until the image is loaded before you get the size of the image. Try something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Q9Vge/)

Comment: @rdck - The sample HTML sucks, if the image has no source, how do you expect it to have a width ?

Comment: It does have a width, obviously, I was just posting the HTML structure. JEEZ.

Comment: more efficient if you can set dimensions and class in image tags with server code, wouldn't have to wait for full image to load

Comment: @charlietfl I can do this, no problem. How would the jQuery change?

Comment: add the class on server at same time, no jQuery needed and css would be be immediate on page load

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `load` instead, when DOM is ready only `img` tag is defined but the image isn't loaded yet. Its size comes when it's fully loaded

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var image = $('.work-each img');
    if (image.width() < 500) {
        $('.work-text').addClass('work-text-small');
    }
});
```

However as @rdck pointed if there are more images with `class=".work-each img"` code won't work so in that case you go trough each image and apply the class

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var image = $('.work-each img');
    image.each(function () {
        var that = $(this);
        if (that.width() < 500) {
            that.next('div.work-text').addClass('work-text-small');
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: I think there needs to be an .each function in this? So it runs through each one and adds a class to $(this)? Otherwise will it not add the class to every .work-text div that exists if at least one of the images is smaller than 500?

Comment: Indeed, good point. The exmple was with a single div so I was mislead

Answer (score 1):

If you get dimensions using server code and set class accordingly, there would be no need to wait for image to load and css would immediately take effect as soon as html exists